# What is the meaning of the SVN statuses ContentStatus, NodeStatus, PropertyStatus, TextStatus?

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn, sharpsvn

I am writing a hookscript for TortoiseSVN using C# and [SharpSvn](https://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/).

It needs to get a list of external files/dirs that have been modified. I am using the method `SvnClient.Status()` that recursively returns [`SvnStatusEventArgs`](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/?topic=html/T_SharpSvn_SvnStatusEventArgs.htm) objects. These objects have the properties `LocalContentStatus`, `LocalNodeStatus`, `LocalPropertyStatus` and `LocalTextStatus`. I know that i have to use these properties to determine what I am dealing with (an external link, a modified file, ...) but I don't know what these properties exactly mean.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think `LocalTextStatus` is some kind of display name of the status and `LocalPropertyStatus` is the status of the path's properties (e.g. svn:externals or svn:needs-lock).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`ContentStatus` refers to the status of the file contents. For example if you have modified a file, its `ContentStatus` would be `modified`. `ContentStatus` for a folder is not used and either `none` or not set.

`PropertyStatus` refers to the properties of the file or folder.

`NodeStatus` refers to the file or folder itself. For example status like `added`, `deleted` would show up here, but of course not a status like `modified`